# customize bootstrap widths do not know how

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I need to implement the following custom widths for a website I am creating but not clear on how to do this to override the bootstrap defaults:

- width of website: 1590px;
- container width: 1530px;
- column gutters: 30px;
- column widths: 230px;

I know that you should not touch the bootstrap default css file, so if I create a custom.css file, what do I put it in it?

I dont know LESS/SASS though.

Comment: Can't you create a custom bootstrap depending on your needs ? http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Comment: The bootstrap is already implemented, so I cannot touch it, unless I override it in my own custom.css file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I recommand not to use a fixed width in pixels for the container, because then you loose responsive behavior. Use a percentage value instead (default is 100%), define a max-width: 1590px; for container and use a padding: 0 30px; for the left and right spacing.

In Bootstrap all columns use percentage values, too. A column of 230px width you get by using the col classes for 1/6 ( see more here: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-options)

And the gutter-width of 30px is the Bootstrap default gutter-width, 15px left & right.

Comment: So in my custom.css, do I do this only @media queries, or do I simply write: .container {max-width: 1590px; width: 1530px; padding: 0 30px;} ?? Would it be possible if you could write out the specifics on how to do in this CSS, Im finding this a little confusing...

Comment: In your custom CSS you write:

        container {
        max-width: 1530px;
        padding: 0 30px;
        margin: auto;
        }

Don't use width: 1530px; - then class container is not responsive anymore. Default container width is 100% - so you will use always 100% of the viewport until viewport becomes larger than 1590px. To keep the container div in the middle of the viewport, use margin: auto;

Comment: Thanks, Shivatomix, however, its not being responsive at all...I am not sure what my @media queries should be if I need: width of website: 1590px; container width: 1530px; column gutters: 30px; column widths: 230px;

Comment: DO NOT give any of them a width! That is destroying responsiveness. What is "website"? "Website" is the body element, which should be 100% of the viewport - no matter, on which device! So don't give any pixel width setting to it. Class container defines your content div. Don't give it a width in pixels, leave it with 100% width and define a max-width of 1530px. 
Then you don't need any media query for it! On small screens, container will take 100% of viewport minus the padding left and right. If viewport becomes larger than 1590px, the max-width setting avoids the container getting bigger.

Answer (score 0):

Rule number one with bootstrap is to never change Something on the files ^^ so if you Want Something like that,  the best is to create another CSS file,  copy bootstrap on it and make some modification

Comment: Thanks Jacky-Marley, this might be a suitable solution, as I need to keep it responsive as well. Regarding the bootstrap CSS, which one do I copy and modify to overwrite? would it be the bootstrap.min.css, correct?

Answer (score 0):

> Simply override the existing bootstrap's class in your custom CSS.

For eg:

CSS:

```
.container { 
      width: 1530px;
 }
```

Similarly, other classes can have new values of the existing properties of Bootstrap.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however I have tried this, and since making it a fixed width, it will not be responsive for mobile/tablet, etc.

Comment: I didn't knew  that you are working with responsive layout, as the question didn't mentioned about it. Since you are working with mobile, then the best thing is to make use of `container-fluid`, provided by bootstrap itself. And if you want to work with the fixed layouts, plus also support mobile, then you are sacrificing responsive behavior by introducing *horizontal scroll*, where the device's width < container's width.

Comment: The thing is the website does not make use of container-fluid because I am not using the entire width of the screen on a desktop, so I have to leave it as 'container'. I just need to extend the width of container though, and that has to be kept fluid to enable bootstraps other default styling for responsiveness...

Comment: In that case you should specify `min-width` for `container` in different break points using *media queries*.

Comment: Ah, right...that's where I am having problems as well. So in my css i specify min-width and make media queries as well? I dont know exactly how to specify these in the media queries for these widths, and how am I sure that 1590px will work if my desktop is not that wide? : 
    width of website: 1590px;
    container width: 1530px;
    column gutters: 30px;
    column widths: 230px;
arghh, I am learning media queries, but don't have a good understanding on them yet :/ BTW: thanks a lot for your help, Shashank

Comment: You should specify `min-width`, in the media query itself. Eg: for desktops -> `@media (min-width: 1024px){ .container {min-width: 1024px; /*or go with 1530px*/}}`. For mobile -> `@media (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 767px) { .container {min-width: 320px;}}`. For tablets-> `@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1023px) { .container {min-width: 768px;}}`